# Как сделать редирект всех страниц на определенную

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Всем привет! Есть сайт site.ru с различными категориями и подкатегориями, необходимо сделать редирект всех страниц на site.ru/lp/, то есть на лендинг. Как это правильно сделать?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сдела так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lp/.*
RewriteRule .  /lp/  [R=301,L]
```